# Batch/CMD File Accept User Input for Timeout

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64

I'm looking for a way to accept user input for `timeout` in a batch file.
Basically, when the batch program starts, the user will have the option to input a timeout in minutes which will be calculated into seconds and passed as a variable until the next step proceeded.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything on the web ;(

```
@echo off
REM set timeout by using the input of the user
shutdown -f -s -t (here comes in user input * 60)
```

Would something like this be possible with CMD?

Comment: What exact strings did you search for? Because `set /p` will do what you want.

Comment: I did found `set /p` but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: The usage for set /p is `set /p variable=prompt` where `prompt` is what the script shows the user when it asks for input and `variable` is the variable that the input gets stored in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p TIMEOUT="In how many minutes should the server shut down? "
set /a TIMEOUT = %TIMEOUT% * 60
```

This will set the TIMEOUT variable to whatever the user enters. As per your initial post, you could then call it with 
`shutdown -f -s -t %TIMEOUT%`

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a native `TIMEOUT` method for this:

```
set /p mtime="Enter time in minutes: "
set /a stime=%mtime%*60
timeout /t %stime%
```

Append `/nobreak` to ignore user key strokes. Otherwise if the user does press a key, execution will resume immediately.

Comment: Thank you for that @meatspace!
Your approach as well works, but I'm familiar with the suggestion of @theglossy1

If I could I would mark the suggestion as correct answer!